# Ruby create a class from a specification file

Tags: ruby

I have a specification file `Spec.txt` like this

```
 title     :Test
 attribute :fieldOne, String
 attribute :fieldTwo,  Fixnum
 constraint :fieldOne, 'fieldOne != nil'
 constraint :fieldTwo, 'fieldTwo >= 0'
```

from which I need to dynamically create a class with classname `Test` and the attributes `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` and the constraints of the attributes.
I got so far to read in the file split up the lines and store them into arrays and then dynamically create the class with

```
 dynamic_name = @@TITLE
    Object.const_set(dynamic_name, Class.new { 
        def init *args
        ...
        end
        })
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way to go or even how to create the attributes and the constraints now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be:

```
file=File.open('Spec.txt')
attrs=[]
constraints=[]
all_attrs=""
new_class=""
file.each do |line|
  if line =~ /title/
    value= line.split[1].tr(':,','')
    new_class=value
  elsif line =~ /attribute/
    value= line.split[1]
    attrs << value
  elsif line =~ /constraint/
    field= line.split[2].tr('\'','')
    constraint= line.split[3]
    constraints << "\n  def #{field}=\n    validation here (#{constraint}) \n  end\n"
  end
end

attrs.map!{|attr| attr+" "}
all_attrs.chomp!(", ")
all_constraints=constraints.join

result=
  "Class "+new_class+"\n"+
  "attr_reader "+
  "#{all_attrs}\n"+
  "#{all_constraints}\n"+
  "end\n"

printf "#{result}"
```

run:

```
$ ruby create_class.rb 
Class Test
attr_reader :fieldOne, :fieldTwo

  def fieldOne=
    validation here (!=) 
  end

  def fieldTwo=
    validation here (>=) 
  end

end
$
```

Needs some more work on the validations but you get the idea.

To use immediately you could send the output to a ruby file and then include it as code, e.g.

```
# You would add this after the first section of code, after the 'printf "#{result}"'
File.open("#{new_class}.rb", "w") do |file|
  file.write(result)
end

require_relative "#{new_class}.rb"

test_it= Object.const_get(new_class).new
puts "#{test_it}"
```

Otherwise if creating the ruby file is enough:

```
ruby create_class.rb > class.rb
```

As Vaughan suggested.